# What's the result of (i++&&j)?

Tags: logic, operators, increment

I have a problem with understanding this expression.

```
(i++&&j)+4*i=? 
// i=4, j=4
```

What's the result of this ? Program gives me 25. I assumed that before incrementation it virtually gives me 21.

Comment: This is a homework/test isn't it? ;)

Comment: that gives me 21 when I run it in C

Comment: Yes,that's part of tricky test :P

Comment: without specifying a language there is no one answer to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose it depends on the language (and its compiler) Because it depends when `i` will get incremented and also how `&&` boolean operator works or what it returns.

In Javascript at least it works like this:

1. `(i++ && j)` is evaluated first and calculated as 4 && 4 which results in 4
2. After this is calculated, `i` is being incremented to 5
3. Then the second part is being calculated which is 4*5 = 20
4. This is then added and result in Javascript is therefore **24**.

### Some additional info about Javascript boolean operators

It may be that this is because Javascript is not strongly typed language but every non-zero, non-empty, not-null and defined value is truthy. The last truthy value will be returned after boolen expression is evaluated

Therefore:

- `4 (truthy) && 4 (truthy)` will return `4`
- `4 (truthy) && 0 (falsey)` will return `0`
- `0 && 4` will return `0`
- `10 && 4` will return `4` - last truthy value
- `false && 4` will return `false`
- `4 && null && 5` will return `null`
- `4 && new Date()` will return moment-specific date
- etc.

Answer (score 0):

I get 21 when I run it in C. `(i++&&j)` should evaluate to 1, as the `&&` is a logical AND operator. Then `4*i`, i here is 5 as it has been incremented after its last use was evaluated, so 1 + 4*5 = 21.

Thats just how I see it fitting together.

## EDIT

Basically it depends on the operator precedence in the language that it is written, hence differing results.

Answer (score 0):

I compiled it in C. It gave me 21 when i used single printf only to display this expression. Although It gave me 25 when i use this expression "twice" in printf. Problem solved. Thank you all for help.